# Nginx upstream block host not found

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a nginx container where it maps to another backend container. When I tried adding upstream block in nginx.conf which is like

```
upstream backend_servers {
    server backend:8000;
}
```

The error that is occuring is

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "backend:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
```

But If I place the same block in default.conf it works the container is running successfully. What is the issue with nginx.conf file

Comment: Is the backend container linked properly in docker?

Comment: Where do you put default.conf and is the folder you're putting it to included in nginx.conf (like this: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`)?